# download only selected rows in Tabulator table?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Looking for guidance on how to download a (CSV) containing only the selected rows from a Tabulator table.

I am using a row selector like this:

```js
{title: "Selector", formatter: "rowSelection", titleFormatter: "rowSelection", align: "center", headerSort: false, cellClick: function (e, cell) {
   cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
}}
```

1. I found no examples or questions on this and the documentation (while good) didn't reveal an easy approach.
2. I had no luck finding the .download method as part of anything but the table object.
3. I had no luck attempting to filter the table by selected, then download, and then unfilter.  Filters appear to work on underlying data fields and this Selected column is not found although I suppose I could consider managing a data field for this in code.
4. I have considered the approach of creating a second table, copying the selected rows onto it and then downloading that before destroying it, but have not attempted.
5. I have considered the approach of creating a custom download function which is documented, but have not attempted.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im afraid this isnt currently possible as a built in feature at the moment, but this will be coming in the 4.7 release.

But your approach of filtering the table is a good approach, you would need to use the ***rowSelected*** and ***rowDeselected*** callbacks to toggle a property on the row data:

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowSelected:function(row){
        row.update({selected:true});
    },
     rowDeselected:function(row){
        row.update({selected:false});
    },
});
```

and then filter the table by this value:

```js
table.setFilter("selected", "=", true);
```

Comment: First, thank you for very much your help! 

I thought this was working great but just noticed an unexpected behavior. It seems that clicking the header to toggle select/deselect-all these row level events never fire so the selected flag gets out of sync. I am looking possibly leveraging rowSelectionChanged or headerClick to work around this. Any thoughts?   

And while I know that this functionality will be available soon for downloading I am now using this same approach to manage selected markers on a google map, so still will need to solve.

Comment: I am now scanning the whole table on rowSelectionChanged call back and comparing/updating the "isSelected" data to row.isSelected() and it is working great but does feel a bit cloodgey.  I am going to open an issue in GIT on these events not firing, it really makes them unusable for tracking selection.

Answer (score 0):

**POSSIBLE && TESTED**

Unfortunately theres no native function to do it, but i found a work around to achieve this functionality.

Short Story

1. Create another hidden table div (lets say table2)
2. Select Rows from table1 (by clicking or by function)
3. Get Selected data by

var rows = table.getData("selected")

4. Init table2 pass rows as data (follow SoPs for columns)
5. Pass this hidden table to CSV/PDF function to download CSV/PDF.

//you can change type to CSV for CSV download

table2.download("pdf", "data.pdf", {
orientation: "portrait", //set page orientation to portrait
title: "Example Report", //add title to report
});