# Download only selected rows in react Tabulator in xlsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, xlsx, tabulator

I am new to tabulator and react. I am trying to download only the selected rows which are checked in the tabulator table in the excel file. However I am not able to find any documentation on the same or any solution for the same.

I tried to implement this solution from Oli. However it is not working.

[download only selected rows in Tabulator table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60779025/download-only-selected-rows-in-tabulator-table)

Can anybody please help with a solution to this?

Here is my code:

the table formation:

```
const columnsSickWagon = [
    {
      formatter: "rowSelection",
      titleFormatter: "rowSelection",
      hozAlign: "center",
      headerSort: false,
      selectable:true,
      
       **rowSelected:function(row){
        row.update({selected:true});
    },
        rowDeselected:function(row){
        row.update({selected:false});
    },**
    },
    {
      title: "Train No",
      field: "trainNo",
      align: "center",
      headerFilter: "input",
      headerFilterPlaceholder: "search...",
    },
    .....
```

I am using the bolded section as Oli mentioned in his solution

The download Function:

```
var sickWagonListmapref = null;
  const downloadSickWagonData = async () => {
    
    
    var table = sickWagonListmapref.table;
     table.setFilter("selected", "=", true);
    
    const date = new Date();
    const fileName = "Sick Wagon Data" + date.toString() + ".xlsx";
    table.download("xlsx", fileName, { sheetName: "Sheet1" });
  };
```

React Render:

```
<ReactTabulator
          ref={(ref) => {
            sickWagonListmapref = ref;
          }}
          data={datasourceSickWagonData}
          columns={columnsSickWagon}
          options={{
            layout: "fitDataFill",
            height: 400,
            // pagination: "local",
            // paginationSize: 10,
            downloadDataFormatter: (data) => data,
            downloadReady: (fileContents, blob) => blob,
          }}
        />
```

On trying to implement Olis solution what happens is the table goes blank and I get empty values in the excel.

Please help in this.